# How to use different registry for a single node module?

Tags: node.js, npm

We have a bunch of private node modules maintained in our internal registry. Is there a way I can specify the internal registry for our private modules alone? I know this is possible using @scope. Unfortunately, the internal registry that we use doesn't support scopes yet.

Comment: Why don't you use Yarn with specifying git repo such as "yarn add https://github.com/mycompany/mylib#0.1.0" ?

Comment: We use mono-repo for our node modules. Per my understanding, it is not possible to point to a folder path within git repo while mentioning dependencies. Is it possible?